Create report on parent object based on child object
We have a requirement to create a report that shows all accounts for which opportunities were created in last seven days with certain values. an account should be shown only once even if there are more than one opportunities created. we have created a report by grouping data based on account but it shows the sum of opportunities as the filter is on opportunity.
any help on how we can build this report will be appreciated.

Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour]. Have you tried cross-filters?  Please [edit] your post to include details / screenshots of your report type and filters.
